# Sending custom C struct in mpi

Tags: c, struct, mpi

Trying to send an array of my data structure, I receive a strange error which, however, does not stop my execution and the data sent seems arrive correctly.
Doing various propre I noticed that the offset calculated by the "offestof" function changes according to the size of the word array but not uniformly.

My struct

```
#define WORD_SIZE 40

typedef struct Word{
    char word[WORD_SIZE];
    int frequecy;
}Word;
```

How i commit it

```
    MPI_Datatype types[2] = {MPI_CHAR, MPI_INT};
    int blocklengths[2] = {WORD_SIZE,1};
    MPI_Aint offsets[2] = {
        offsetof(Word, word),
        offsetof(Word, frequecy),
    };
    
    printf("%ld %ld\n",offsetof(Word, word),offsetof(Word, frequecy));

    MPI_Datatype MPI_MY_WORD;
    MPI_Type_create_struct(2, blocklengths, offsets, types, &MPI_MY_WORD);
    MPI_Type_commit(&MPI_MY_WORD);
```

Executing an execution with `WORD_SIZE 40` i get this error `[a1e112a4a20e:02386] Read -1, expected 114180, errno = 1`

and the printf prints `0 40`.

Instead by setting `WORD_SIZE` to 30 I have no error and the prinf prints `0 32`.

I do not understand why the offset values ​​do not change uniformly and why only in some values ​​of WORD_SIZE I have errors from mpi.

Here is the part of the code where I send and receive the data.

```
if(rank == 1){
        ...
        to_send_array[size];
        ...
        MPI_Send(to_send_array, size, MPI_MY_WORD, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }else if(rank == 0){

        MPI_Status status;
        Word buff[size];

        MPI_Recv(buff, size, MPI_MY_WORD, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        printf("P(%d) first elemeent %s %d\n",rank,buff[0].word,buff[0].frequecy);


    }
```

I am using Open MPI 2.1.1

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: Please edit your question with a [mcve] and state which MPI library (vendor and version) you are using.

Comment: The bug could be anywhere, including the code you did not show, hence the need for a [mcve]

Comment: with `WORD_SIZE=30`, the compiler adds 2 bytes of padding before `frequency` so it can be aligned on an `int`

Comment: Why with `WORD_SIZE = 40`, the compiler doesn't add two bytes of padding?

Comment: `frequency` is an `int` and hence must be aligned on 4 `bytes`. `40 = 4 * 10`, no padding needed. `30 = 4 * 7 + 2` so `2` bytes padding is needed.

Comment: in order to be usable, your code must compile.